# Hash remove all except specific keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to remove every key from a hash except a given key.

For example:

```
{
 "firstName": "John",
 "lastName": "Smith",
 "age": 25,
 "address":
 {
     "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
     "city": "New York",
     "state": "NY",
     "postalCode": "10021"
 },
 "phoneNumber":
 [
     {
       "type": "home",
       "number": "212 555-1234"
     },
     {
       "type": "fax",
       "number": "646 555-4567"
     }
 ]
}
```

I want to remove everything except "firstName" and/or "address".

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Some other options:

```
h.select {|k,v| ["age", "address"].include?(k) }
```

Or you could do this:

```
class Hash
  def select_keys(*args)
    select {|k,v| args.include?(k) }
  end
end
```

So you can now just say:

```
h.select_keys("age", "address")
```

Comment: I like using the array so that its very quick an easy to add new keys instead of more OR statements.  The Hash extension is also kinda cool :)

Comment: Thanks. Much more comprehensive answer!

Comment: Is this only for rails? or ruby in general?

Comment: New visitors, check the `slice` answer with a score of 200 below. It's the prefered answer.

Answer (score 319):

What about [`Hash#slice`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Hash.html#method-i-slice)?

```
hash.slice('firstName', 'lastName')
 # => { 'firstName' => 'John', 'lastName' => 'Smith' }
```

Available in Ruby since 2.5

Comment: The question didn't specifically mention Rails, but it is tagged as such. This is the best option when using Rails or core_ext.

Comment: Yes, this is the reason I suggested `slice`.

Comment: this answer should be first one!

Comment: @DimaMelnik Hashes don't inherently have an order.

Comment: [Hash#slice](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-slice) is pure Ruby now, Rails is not needed.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Simply, clean and without garbage code.

Answer (score 8):

If you use Rails, please consider ActiveSupport `except()` method: http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/except

```
hash = { a: true, b: false, c: nil}
hash.except!(:c) # => { a: true, b: false}
hash # => { a: true, b: false }
```

Comment: Except keeps everything except the given. The reverse of what the question is about.

Answer (score 6):

Hash#select does what you want:

```
   h = { "a" => 100, "b" => 200, "c" => 300 }
   h.select {|k,v| k > "a"}  #=> {"b" => 200, "c" => 300}
   h.select {|k,v| v < 200}  #=> {"a" => 100}
```

Edit (for comment):

assuming h is your hash above:

```
h.select {|k,v| k == "age" || k == "address" }
```

Comment: What if I want to select "age" and "address" from my example?

Answer (score 5):

```
hash = { a: true, b: false, c: nil }
hash.extract!(:c) # => { c: nil }
hash # => { a: true, b: false }
```

Comment: This excludes the keys specified, rather than includes the keys specified. the difference is subtle but important

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Jake Dempsey's answer, this one should be faster for large hashes, as it only peaks explicit keys rather than iterating through the whole hash:

```
class Hash
  def select_keys(*args)
    filtered_hash = {}
    args.each do |arg|
      filtered_hash[arg] = self[arg] if self.has_key?(arg)
    end
    return filtered_hash
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

No Rails needed to get a very concise code:

```
keys = [ "firstName" , "address" ]
# keys = hash.keys - (hash.keys - keys) # uncomment if needed to preserve hash order
keys.zip(hash.values_at *keys).to_h
```